# Why does OS X still have so old version of GCC? When will it be updated?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, g++, osx-elcapitan

In the newest version OS X system (El Captain) is still 4.2.1 which was released 28 of July, 2007. When will it be updated? Why does OS X still have so old version of GCC? Why we use in 2016 GCC released in 2007?

Answer (score 1):

That could not be a native installation since 10.11 should run only Xcode 7+, and Xcode 5+ provided clang while removing its gcc 4.2 related parts.  There is a wikipedia page of its history.  Alternatively, you are free to install any version of gcc yourself, newer or older.